# Google play sign in not working in my app

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have written a game and am trying to add the sign in to google play functionality to it but, when I click the button it fails with no error, I have checked the logs and there is no error there either.

Code:

```
GoogleSignInOptions options = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN).build();
apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API,options).build();

public void startSignInIntent() {
    Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(apiClient);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

Edit: I have checked and it is giving me error code 13 when I get

```
result.getStatus().getStatusCode();
```

Comment: Are you testing on an emulator without google play services installed?

Comment: i am testing on my samsung galaxy s7